# Email notification for Channel Form entries only, not CP entries

Tags: safecracker, ee3

I'm on EE3, with a channel where admins post via CP, while guests/member post via Channel Form. Entries posted via the form will be marked with "To Review" status.

Is it possible to set up email notifications for only entries submitted via Channel Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct method. But you can initialize an email function by this hook in your extension file.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extension_hooks/module/channel_form/index.html#channel-form-submit-entry-end